# In C#,How to delete pointer that alloced by c?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

```
#define EXPORT_DLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 

EXPORT_DLL int* alloc(int size)
{
    int* result = new int[size];
    return result;
}
```

and in c#, use P/Inovke to call this function:

```
public class Model
{
    [DllImport("Win32Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "alloc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern static IntPtr Alloc(int size);

    public int[] Data { get; set; }

    public Model(int size)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Alloc(size);
        Data = new int[size];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, Data, 0, Data.Length);
    }
}
```

Then, create a test like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Model> list = new List<Model>();

        list.Add(new Model(10240000));
        list.Add(new Model(10240000));
        list.Add(new Model(10240000));
        list.Add(new Model(10240000));
        list.Add(new Model(10240000));
        list.Clear();
        GC.Collect();

    }
}
```

however, when the GC.Collect() execute, only managed memory were collect. so is there any way to release the memory that alloced by c function?

Answer (score 3):

The C API you are creating needs to expose a deallocation function that your .NET code can call.

There are too many ways memory can be allocated in C/C++ (eg. `new`, `malloc`, `GlobalAlloc`, …) for a single `Marshall.Delete` to work. So add the matching deallocation to your native code to be called from .NET.

(On the .NET side it would be a good idea to look at specialising [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to automate the calling of that deallocation function.)